# Magento2 static-content:deploy not generating admin

Tags: magento2, deploy, folder

When using:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Only the blank and luma theme will be generated but not the admin one.

Does anyone know if there is a setup somewhere to specify the themes?

Answer (score 6):

try to run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml
```

Comment: Strange but actually works for me when using other Locales than en_US. Without "--area" only frontend is generated.

Answer (score 3):

```
--area (-a)
```

Generate files only for the specified areas. The default, with no option specified, is to generate files for all areas. Valid values are `adminhtml` and `frontend`

For admin

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml
```

[Documentation Link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)